# Unexpected line-break with css

Tags: css, html, font-face, word-wrap

On a new project I get some unexpected behavior: When the sidebar is quite small (about 200px) , line breaks occur earlier than needed.

On this image you can see the result (Safari 6.0.2, similar results in other brothers), the left arrow where the word is, the right arrow where the word should be (in my opinion).
[example http://fitzskoglund.jensravens.de/screen.jpg](http://fitzskoglund.jensravens.de/screen.jpg)

You can find the whole website http://fitzskoglund.jensravens.de to the see effect and CSS.

I cannot attach a special snippet because I don't know where this style or behavior comes from.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: In Google Chrome, you can right-click and select Inspect Element to find out where the style comes from.

Comment: Looks to me like it's your font.  If I Inspect Element, and remove the `font-family` declaration in your CSS, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be for lack of a "space" to break at. When I added a space at the end of this...

```
<strong>SCHULD SIND IMMER DIE ANDEREN </strong>
```

...or before this word (which follows the `<a>` wrapping the `<strong>`)...

```
 ausgezeichnet
```

...it seems to work.

Comment: The word 'ausgezeicgnet' is preceded by no-break space (rather than space). That's why line break can't occur there.

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like is happening is the first space in a line is being treated as a `;nbsp`, which is being printed as if there is no whitespace. That causes the two end words to be treated as one. If you were to place a single letter like 'a' before the space by the second word, it works, or place a second space in either line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has to do with the way you have your anchor and strong tags styled. They are interacting with the surrounding text in a weird way, causing it to break apart. When I inspect and remove the text after your anchor ("ausgezeichnet"), the anchor text snaps back into place: http://screencast.com/t/G1imlavU . I would remove what you can and keep the mark-up as simple as possible.